# Convert strings to int or float in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer, double

```
 integer = input("Number: ")
 rslt = int(integer)+2
 print('2 + ' + integer + ' = ' + rslt)
 double = input("Point Number: ")
 print('2.5 + ' +double+' = ' +(float(double)+2.5))
```

Gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...", line 13, in <module>
    print('2 + ' + integer + ' = ' + rslt)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I'm fairly new to programming and my background is mostly just the basics of C# so far. I wanted to try to learn Python through doing all my C# school projects on Python. I'm used to the simple syntax of C# which would look something like this:

```
int integer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
```

or

```
double double = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
```

Which takes a user input string and converts it to what I specified.

I think I read py2.x has a command called raw_input that works a bit better than the input command of py3.x in this regard.

I was trying to find myself a similar format as the one I'm used to in C# to use in Python, but it's proving surprisingly hard just to find a method to convert the user input string into an integer after all this googling and trying everything I could think of (and that I found on google) I decided it was time to ask. Can you help?

Comment: He says python 3 right in the question title

Comment: Why should i rather use string formatting than just a comma?

Comment: The main reasons to use a format string over commas are WYSIWYG (you can immediately tell what your output's going to look like from `'2 + {} = {}'`) and more control even for simple cases, you have to deal with the extra spaces you get from commas). Less important reasons (at least for you) are that formatting is easier to use with dynamic values, easier to internationalize, and more portable between Python 2.x and 3.x. (If you write `print(1,2)`, you get `1 2` in 3.x, but `(1, 2)` in 2.x.)

Answer (score 12):

You have to convert the integer into a string:

```
print('2 + ' + str(integer) + ' = ' + str(rslt))
```

Or pass it as an argument to `print` and print will do it for you:

```
print('2 +', integer, '=', rslt)
```

I would do it using string formatting:

```
print('2 + {} = {}'.format(integer, rslt))
```

Comment: Thank you! that answered everything for me aswell :)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is not with converting the input to an integer.  The problem is that when you write `' = ' + rslt` you are trying to add an integer to a string, and you can't do that.

You have a few options.  You can convert `integer` and `rslt` back into strings to add them to the rest of your string:

```
print('2 + ' + str(integer) + ' = ' + str(rslt))
```

Or you could just print multiple things:

```
print('2 + ', integer, ' = ', rslt)
```

Or use string formatting:

```
print('2 + {0} = {1}'.format(integer, rslt))
```

Comment: Thank you! that answered everything for me.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.x - `input` is the equivalent of Python 2.x's `raw_input`...

You should be using string formatting for this - and perform some error checking:

```
try:
    integer = int(input('something: '))
    print('2 + {} = {}'.format(integer, integer + 2))
except ValueError as e:
    print("ooops - you didn't enter something I could make an int of...")
```

Another option - that looks a bit convoluted is to allow the interpreter to take its best guess at the value, then raise something that isn't `int` or `float`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

try:
    value = literal_eval(input('test: '))
    if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
        raise ValueError
    print value + 2
except ValueError as e:
    print('oooops - not int or float')
```

This allows a bit more flexibility if you wanted complex numbers or lists or tuples as input for instance...

Comment: @user2115045 are you sure? (edit: yes - I didn't paste the last `)` in there...¬)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a value to an integer, use the [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#int) built in function, and to convert a value to a floating point number, use the [`float`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#float) built in function. Then you can use the [`str`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#str) built in function to convert those values back to strings. The built in function [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) returns strings, so you would use these functions in code like this:

```
integer = input("Number: ")
rslt = int(integer)+2
print('2 + ' + integer + ' = ' + str(rslt))
double = input("Point Number: ")
print('2.5 + ' +str(double)+' = ' +str(float(double)+2.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
integer = int(input("Number: "))
print('2 + %d = %d' % (integer, integer + 2))

double = float(input("Point Number: "))
print('2.5 + %.2f = %.2f' % (double, double + 2.5))
```